# What is the correct way to use express with a second div that needs data

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have the following layout.jade file:

```
!!! 5
html
    head
    body
        #left
            #leftbody
        #center
            #centerbody
                #container!= body
        #right
            #rightbody
```

And I have the following route.js file:

```
app.get('/',
    function(req, res) {
        Post.find({}).execFind(
            function(err, data) {
                res.render('post/index', {
                    posts: data
                });
        });
});
```

I'm currently rendering `#centerbody` based on links in the `#leftbody`.  I'm wondering how I could use express to populate the `#rightbody`.  Currently I'm populating a `ul` in `#rightbody` using an ajax call in `document.ready` but was wondering if there was another way using express.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What, exactly, do you want to put in `rightbody`?

Comment: Here is the url to the site I'm working on as an example http://50.56.194.85/.  The center div receives all the renders based on the links in the resources div while currently I'm populating the sponsored links div via an ajax call when the page loads.  What I'm asking is if that's the correct practice in express or if there is another option.  It works but if feels like a kludge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly advise you to have a look at Jade [includes](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/Readme.md#includes), or, even better, Jade [template inheritance](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/blob/master/Readme.md#template-inheritance)

This would allow you to keep, for all your pages, the common parts of the page in separated files. And allow easier maintenance. This is definitely the thing to do.